# How do I add a custom mime type to CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types

I'm creating an upload form using CodeIgniter and I'd like to upload a plaintext file with a .out extension. In my controller I've set the following options:

```
// Set upload variables
$uploadConfig['upload_path'] = 'uploads/temp/';
$uploadConfig['allowed_types'] = 'out|txt';
$uploadConfig['max_size'] = '1024';

$this->load->library('upload', $uploadConfig);
```

In the mimes.php config file, I have the following:

```
'text'  =>  'text/plain',
'out'   =>  'text/plain',
```

And in my httpd.conf file on my server, I've added the line:

```
AddType text/plain .out
```

Whenver I try to upload a .out file, I get the error message `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.` An identical file with a .txt extension uploads just fine.

Any thoughts on how to get this custom mime type to work with CI? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it should work.  The Upload class just explodes the 'allowed_types' string at the pipe separator, then checks if the file extension is in the array.

Does it work if you use '*' as the allowed_types config setting?

Comment: Yes, it does! Well, that's good. Any thoughts on why specifying the allowed_types is problematic?

Comment: I was able to fix this by setting the mime type for `'out'` to `array('text/plain', 'application/octet-stream')` instead of just `'text/plain'`.

I'm guessing this has to do with the browser not knowing the mime type of the .out file and simply using application/octet-stream.